# Russian - English Multitran dictionary

Tags: translation

Maybe, someone knows what is the best way to retrieve translations from it.
Is there a library for reading  Multitran dictionary database?
My goal is simple program which will retrieve English translation given a word in Russian.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can use StarDic dictionaries? Here you can find English-Russian http://abloz.com/huzheng/stardict-dic/ru/

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/StarDict

Its open source software so should not be a problem to use it in your programm.

http://code.google.com/p/stardict-3/

Comment: Thank you. It may be a solution, however Multitran has 1 million entries and actually it looks like one can freely use its database in Linux. I just need a way to  get translations programmatically.

Comment: http://www.multitran.ru/c/m.exe?a=2&l1=1&l2=2 here Russian forum on Multitran you can ask there.

Answer (score 0):

It is what I work on these days. It's not a library, it's a Telegram bot, but you could adapt the code to your requirements.

[Multitran-telegram-bot on GitHub](https://github.com/Highstaker/Multitran-telegram-bot)